# Double dispatch inside a single inheritance tree

Tags: c#, inheritance, dynamic, dispatch, visitor-pattern

I have an inheritance tree of different `Line`-classes, starting with the abstract `Line`-class. I want to be able to intersect each line with each other line, and sometimes, I do not know neither of the runtime types, e.g. I'm calling `Line.Intersect(Line)` (so I need double dispatch). This will always call the most abstract overload of the overriden `Intersect`-methods, e.g. `Circle.Intersect(Line)` instead of `Circle.Intersect(actualType)`. Here's some example code:

```
class Program
{
  static void Main(string[] args)
  {
    Line straightLine = new StraightLine();
    Line circle = new Circle();

    // Will print: "Circle intersecting a line."
    // But should print: "Circle intersecting a straight line."
    circle.Intersect(straightLine);

    Console.ReadLine();
  }
}


abstract class Line
{
  public abstract void Intersect(Line line);

  public abstract void Intersect(StraightLine straightLine);

  public abstract void Intersect(Circle circle);
}


class StraightLine : Line
{
  public override void Intersect(Line line)
  {
    Console.WriteLine("Straigth line intersecting a line.");
  }

  public override void Intersect(StraightLine straightLine)
  {
    Console.WriteLine("Straight line intersecting a straight line.");
  }

  public override void Intersect(Circle circle)
  {
    Console.WriteLine("Straight line intersecting a circle.");
  }
}


class Circle : Line
{
  public override void Intersect(Line line)
  {
    Console.WriteLine("Circle intersecting a line.");
  }

  public override void Intersect(Circle circle)
  {
    Console.WriteLine("Circle intersecting a circle.");
  }

  public override void Intersect(StraightLine straightLine)
  {
    Console.WriteLine("Circle intersecting a straight line.");
  }
}
```

One possible workaround is to use `dynamic`, which I currently do. However, I want to migrate to a .NET Standard-library, where `dynamic` is not allowed.

Are there other ways to make this work? I'd be willing to switch the abstract class for one or multiple interfaces, if that helps. Maybe the visitor-pattern is applicable, although I've only seen this used for different inheritance trees (and find it quite ugly).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to emulate double dispatch by using reflection. Targeting .NET Standard 1.1 and using the Nuget-Package `System.Reflection`, the `Intersect(Line line)`-method does not need be abstract or virtual, but only has to be implemented once.

This is the whole example code for the .NET Standard library (I now return a `string` instead of using `Console.WriteLine()`, since the latter is not available in .NET Standard):

```
using System.Reflection;

namespace IntersectLibrary
{
  public abstract class Line
  {
    public string Intersect(Line line)
    {
      var method = this.GetType().GetRuntimeMethod(nameof(Intersect), new[] { line.GetType() });
      return (string)method.Invoke(this, new[] { line });
    }

    public abstract string Intersect(StraightLine straightLine);

    public abstract string Intersect(Circle circle);
  }


  public class StraightLine : Circle
  {
    public override string Intersect(StraightLine straightLine)
    {
      return "Straight line intersecting a straight line.";
    }

    public override string Intersect(Circle circle)
    {
      return "Straight line intersecting a circle.";
    }
  }


  public class Circle : Line
  {
    public override string Intersect(Circle circle)
    {
      return "Circle intersecting a circle.";
    }

    public override string Intersect(StraightLine straightLine)
    {
      return "Circle intersecting a straight line.";
    }
  }
}
```

Please note that when targeting .NET Framework, `System.Reflection` offers different methods, and the code will need to be modified.

In a console application, the following will happen:

```
using System;
using IntersectLibrary;

namespace ConsoleApplication
{
  class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      Line straightLine = new StraightLine();
      Line circle = new Circle();
      Circle circle2 = new Circle();

      // Calls "Line.Intersect(Line)", and correctly
      // prints "Circle intersecting a straight line.".
      Console.WriteLine(circle.Intersect(straightLine));

      // Also calls "Line.Intersect(Line)",
      // since the argument's compile-time type is "Line".
      Console.WriteLine(circle2.Intersect(straightLine));

      // Calls "Line.Intersect(Circle)",
      // since the argument's compile-time type is "Circle".
      // At runtime, the call will be resolved to
      // "StraightLine.Intersect(Circle)" via single dispatch.
      Console.WriteLine(straightLine.Intersect(circle2));

      Console.ReadLine();
    }
  }
}
```

If you now have one object of compile-time type `Line` and one of a concrete type (e.g. `Circle`), it's better to call `Line.Intersect(Circle)`, since this won't need the (slower) reflection to resolve the method call. However, `Circle.Intersect(Line)` will also work, and most importantly, calling `Line.Intersect(Line)` is now always possible.